# How to group various similar search keywords and find top 100 keywords from big dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, data-science-model, word2vec

I have search keywords in one of my database table. These are the keywords searched by users on a website.
My requirement is to find the top 100 search keywords **after consolidating various similar search keywords.**

e.g. COVID19, Covid 19, Corona, Corona virus, covid-19 are all related to corona and it should be grouped under **Corona**.

OR

blockchain, BLOCKCHAIN, Blockchain business, B L O C K C H A I N are all related to Blockchain so it should be grouped under **Blockchain** category.

I tried to do this using fuzzywuzzy python library but fuzzywuzzy needs a list to be compared with the search keywords. 
And unfortunately I don't have that list because it can be anything based on user's search.

Any suggestions on the approach would really help.

Comment: Did you try from difflib import get_close_matches? I also assume you are removing space/punctuation and making it all in same cases before processing?There is stemming/lemmatization also in nltk. I am not sure it would be helpful in this case though.

Comment: I haven't tried but is it not similar to fuzzywuzzy where we can compare two words and see if they are close match ? And how will it help in the cases like Artificial Intelligence is same as AI. And Covid is same as Corona. Lets say I have 100 words, then do you suggest comparing first word with rest 99 and so on. And yes I am doing preprocessing of the search keywords.

Comment: It is similar. No I am not suggesting that you compare each word that would not be efficient. What comes to mind is finding similarities.May be clustering ?K-Means?I never tried it in text but sounds suitable.if this helps at all.

Comment: may be this would help-https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

Comment: while I can go through the link, but looks like the post is very old and may be we have a better approach to do it now ? Thank you for finding that link for me.

Comment: This reminds me there is cosine similarity also, i read about a while back. https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/